# Ant: copy a file and add a first line

Tags: ant

With ANT I need to copy a (Java) file and add a first line to the target (package statement). The problem: the **copy** command does not seem to support an *amend* option. The **echo** command could append, but does not allow to take the message from a file. And for the **replace** target I have no idea how to just add some text to the beginning of the whole file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could maybe use the Ant [`<concat>`](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/concat.html) task, something like:

```
<concat destfile="with_package.java">
  <header>package com.xxx.yyy;
</header>
  <filelist dir="." files="without_package.java"/>
</concat>
```

Gives me:

```
$ diff without_package.java with_package.java 
0a1
> package com.xxx.yyy;
```